# How to calculate how many distinct rows based off another row SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, expression

Ok this might be hard for me to explain. I have a report for museum tours. I have a column "Tour#" that when i put as `=CountDitinct(Fields!.......` it works fine, there might be 30 returns but only 3 different TOUR #'s so the total will say Total Tours = 3. But then I have a column that says "Sale?". This column returns data that looks like Y-123, Y-124,Y-125 so if i did the same expression `=CountDistinct(Fields!.........` then it would return as Total Sales = 3. The problem is this, those 3 sales may have all been for 1 TOUR # so it shouldn't return 3 it should return 1. I don't want to know how many tickets were sold I want to know how many Sale tickets were sold as long as the Tour # was different. So since that doesn't make sense probably here's an example, if i have 5 returns for Tour #135, then the Sale? column might look like this Y-123,Y-124,Y-125,N-126,Y-127. That means that my report should look like this:

Total Tours: 1     Sales:1.

Right now as i have it, my return would say 1 for tours but 4 for sales.

Comment: Can't you just group by Tour # in your tablix and then use Count(Fields!Sale.Value) or something to count up the sales for each? You're just trying to list a count of sales for each tour right?

Comment: That would work except I need to group by something else so I can't also group by Tours unfortunately because it's not what they want to see. So lets say im grouping by Museum. I  would need the count of sales as long as the Tour is different. Tour 1 may have 20 people but would only count as one sale since the Tour was on sale let say.  Tour 2 has 10 people but none were Sales and Tour 3 has 3 people all Sales. So theres 3 Tours and 2 Sales. I know it sounds strange but thanks for the reply.